Использование асинхронных функций для значений по умолчанию в SQLAlchemy
Я использую FastAPI, SQLAlchemy и asyncpg (асинхронное подключение к бд)
В моей модели есть колонка:
current_location_id = Column(
    ForeignKey("location.id"),
    default=CarService.get_random_location
)

Функция get_random_location:
@classmethod
async def get_random_location(cls) -> int:
    async with async_session_maker() as session:
        query = select(Location.id)
        instances = await session.execute(query)
        result = await instances.fetchall()

    return random.choice(result)[0]

При попытке такого использования я получаю ошибку:
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'CarService.get_random_location' was never awaited
Как я могу использовать асинхронную функцию для создания значения по умолчанию?
Я не могу использовать синхронную функцию и синхронный менеджер контекста, т.к. соединение с бд асинхронное.
Так же я пробовал использовать asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe, но это не сработало:
current_location_id = Column(
    ForeignKey("location.id"),
    default=asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
        CarService.get_random_location(),
        loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
    )
)


defaul t= await CarService.get_random_location

@СергейШ
Сolumn() это не асинхронная функция, в ней не нужен await

await используется внутри асинхронной функции для вызова другой асинхронной функции

А при чем Сolumn()? async def get_random_location(cls):. а это что по вашему?

Если прописать default= await CarService.get_random_location:
'await' outside async function

default колонки таблицы прописывается в схему базы SQL, там не может быть функций Python, должно быть конкретное заранее известное значение. Рандомное значение явно прописывайте при создании строки.

Думаю, сама идея рандомить значение из бд для установки его здесь как дефолтное не совсем верная.

default=CarService.get_random_location

Вы могли бы просто вычислять current_location_id в момент создания записи в вашей таблице. default правильнее было бы использовать, если ваше значение константное и предсказуемое.
